# Having problems trying to figure out how to print variable values using this new bash-ism I'm exploring

Tags: bash

Good day all. I'm trying to learn if this is possible to do. I've been writing scripts in `#!/bin/sh` mode (interpreted with bash) for a while but am learning about bash-isms and am using `#!/bin/bash`. I am using `shellcheck` and `checkbashisms` to help me and I am wondering if what I hope to accomplish is easy. I'm using `stat -s` in a script which populates variables and I'm trying to cycle through them all to print to screen. Below is the minimal amount of code which demonstrates what I'm asking.

I couldn't quite find a previously asked question which is similar. I have a feeling an array might be the way to accomplish what I'm hoping, but I thought I'd ask about this.

```
!/bin/bash

T_FILE=/var/log/fsck_hfs.log

s_vars=( st_dev=0\
         st_ino=0\
         st_mode=0\
         st_nlink=0\
         st_uid=0\
         st_gid=0\
         st_rdev=0\
         st_size=0\
         st_atime=0\
         st_mtime=0\
         st_ctime=0\
         st_birthtime=0\
         st_blksize=0\
         st_blocks=0\
         st_flags=0 )

eval "$(stat -s "$T_FILE")"

printf "\n\n%d\n\n" "$st_size"

for var in "${s_vars[@]}"; do
        printf "%s\n" "$var"
done
```

As the more seasoned among you will probably notice straight away my `for` loop using that bash-ism will print the literals in s_var and I'd like them to print the values. I'd guess I'm going about this completely the wrong way, so any pointers would be appreciated. I've tried changing the `%s` format specifier in that `for` loop to a `%d` but it correctly points out `invalid number`.

Here is a sample run of my code:

```
king:photosync hank$ ./stat.sh


3614

st_dev=0
st_ino=0
st_mode=0
st_nlink=0
st_uid=0
st_gid=0
st_rdev=0
st_size=0
st_atime=0
st_mtime=0
st_ctime=0
st_birthtime=0
st_blksize=0
st_blocks=0
st_flags=0
king:photosync hank$
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: You loaded some `stat` builtin, right? `stat -s` only throws `invalid option` error, what `stat` are you using?

Comment: @cyrus - I can try that, but I use the shellcheck script and it is 100% clean.

Comment: @KamilCuk - I am not familiar with the ```stat``` built-in. I am using the one supplied with macOS Catalina. that ```-s``` is documented in the man page. And sorry - I should have specified my platform details.

Comment: Och, so you're using BSD stat. GNU stat differs ;) There's [this stat builtin](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/examples/loadables/stat.c#L408), but it's not even shipped with bash on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

t_file=/var/log/fsck_hfs.log

s_vars=(
     # Remove =0
     # remove slashes
     # Just list the names
     # you can safely put newlines and comments in array declaration
     st_blksize
     st_blocks
     st_flags
     # etc...
)

eval "$(stat -s "$t_file")"

for var in "${s_vars[@]}"; do
        printf "%s=%s\n" "$var" "${!var}"
        #                        ^^^^^^^ - bash indirect expansion
done
```

You could for example extract the list of variables from output of the command, assuming the output is nice one line per `var=val`, like:

```
tmp=$(stat -s "$t_file")
s_vars=( $(sed 's/=.*//' <<<"$tmp") )  # I know, shellcheck
eval "$tmp"
for i in "${s_vars[@]}"; do
    ....
```

Comment: thank you so much! That did it. I think I need to read up on indirection expansion.